# Add value to Python multidimensional dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a value, which I need to add it to a multidimensional dict

The problem is that the keys may or may not exist

If they exist, I just want to add it, if not .. I need to create it

What is the best way of doing this, since right now what I have looks pretty bad

```
        if response.get('pages', {}).get(url, {}).get('variations', {}).get('custom_screenshot'):
            response['pages'][url]['variations']['custom_screenshot'][command.get('params')[0]] = output
        elif response.get('pages', {}).get(url, {}).get('variations'):
            response['pages'][url]['variations']['custom_screenshot'] = {command.get('params')[0]: output}
        elif response.get('pages', {}).get(url, {}):
            response['pages'][url]['variations'] = {'custom_screenshot': {command.get('params')[0]: output}}
        elif response.get('pages', {}):
            response['pages']['url'] = {'variations': {'custom_screenshot': {command.get('params')[0]: output}}}
        else:
            response['pages'] = {url: {'variations': {'custom_screenshot': {command.get('params')[0]: output}}}}

        return response
```

Comment: why don't you just use `response['pages'] = {url: {'variations': {'custom_screenshot': {command.get('params')[0]: output}}}}` (the **else** part )?

Comment: @MasoudGheisari - because if the pages key has values, it would be overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use referential nature of Python dictionary.

1. Declare intermediate keys that should be in the final response (in proper order)
2. Loop though the keys calling [`dict.setdefaut`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method to set the inner dictionary **if** it's not there
3. Set unconditional value `output` for the custom key `command.get('params')[0]`

---

```
resp_keys = [url, 'variations', 'custom_screenshot']
pages_dict = resp.setdefault('pages', {})

for k in resp_keys:
    pages_dict = pages_dict.setdefault(k, {})  # return dict under key k
pages_dict[command.get('params')[0]] = output
```